# Transform tags XML to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping

I´m new with XSLT and I'm trying to transform a XML in other.

The source XML is something like that:

```
<NoticeContent>
      <Version> 1.0 </Version>
      <Publisher>me</Publisher> 
      <Specification>1</Specification>
      <Instance>1</Instance>
      <NewState>10</NewState>
      <Info>
        <SDTInInfoExtra>
            <Name> Client</Name>
            <Value> 1 </Value>
        </SDTInInfoExtra>
        <SDTInInfoExtra>
            <Name> LocalId </Name>
            <Value>10 </Value>
        </SDTInInfoExtra>      
      </Info>
</NoticeContent>
```

And the expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NoticeContent>
    <Version></Version>
    <Timestamp></Timestamp>
    <Publisher></Publisher>
    <Instance></Instance>
    <NewState></NewState>
    <Info>
        <Characteristic name="Client" value="1" />
        <Characteristic name="LocalId" value="10" />
    </Info>
</NoticeContent>
```

I'm trying with the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Info">
        <xsl:for-each select="SDTInInfoExtra">
            <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
            <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is trying to convert the tags like:

```
<SDTInInfoExtra>
       <Name> LocalId </Name>
        <Value>10 </Value>
</SDTInInfoExtra>
```

into:

```
 <Characteristic name="Client" value="1" />
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started with

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

so the rest is easy:

```
<xsl:template match="SDTInInfoExtra">
  <Characteristic name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! I found another solution using: "attribute name" but yours is shorter and better.